# Changing the KeystoneJs List does not reflect in mongoDB collection

Tags: keystonejs

I explain the situation with a simple example and a pseudo code. This is my `products` schema in KeystoneJs:

```
ProductSchema.add({
    title: { type : String}
})
```

After adding 1000 products, customer wants me to add a `published` field to products model, so I changed the code as follow :

```
ProductSchema.add({
    title: { type : String},
    published: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
    }
})
```

Now when I want to find all published products I do this:

```
ProductModel.model.find({published: true});
```

But this query returns nothing, I know the reason is that when I added `published` field to `productSchema`  this change is not reflected in the database, Now how to make keystone to add a `published` field to every document in MongoDB collection?

Comment: You can apply data/schema changes to existing documents using Keystone's [Application Updates](https://keystonejs.com/documentation/database/application-updates) framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing keystone schema does not affect database, this means next time you create entry, it will populate defaults. I am not sure if it also updates defaults on fetch from db (i remember seeing something similar in code but that may be for something else).

You have to run custom query, either standalone script or as  part of your overall app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you show me some example of how a custom query would look like?